# How to have Watir browser read returned text (not html)?

Tags: watir

In one of our tests, a form submits via Watir, and the server returns a text stream with no html in it at all.

Can I read that text via Watir in some way and parse it for the snippet I'm looking for?  Using `browser.text.include?` gives a message about not finding the `<body`> tag, which makes sense if html is assumed.

Comment: What happens if you ask for `browser.html`?

Comment: I tried that but got a series of messages, each stating `Rescued from "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError waiting for doc.body failed, retrying"`

Comment: Can you show the code to reproduce this behavior as it seems weird?

Comment: I wish I could, but it's essentially a form post to a third party site.  They return this XML to us, as seen at http://jsfiddle.net/mFPVy/ -- and the code which follows is `browser.html.include? "PayPal"`, which is where the series of messages I mentioned above starts.